# Store php datetime in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I can't believe I can't do this, but I want to be able to store the current date and time from php in to a mysql table.

The column in the table is type datetime.
I've tried this

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$my_date = strtotime($current_date);
INSERT INTO my_table (date_time) VALUES ('$my_date')
```

but my timestamp comes up as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

This must be so easy to do but I just can't get it working!
I want to use the timestamp from php rather than using the mysql now() function

Comment: if the mysql field is a `DATETIME`, drop the `strtime` call

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't save it as the Unix Timestamp (which `strtotime()` outputs), but as "2012-12-02 13:00" into the DATETIME column.

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel so dumb!

Answer (score 51):

Try this:

```
$my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
INSERT INTO my_table (date_time) VALUES ('$my_date');
```

In the date-format parameter of the date function, use :
'H' for 24hr format
'h' for 12hr format

Answer (score 2):

Create column type TIMESTAMP and set it to NOT NULL. Then pass in NULL during INSERT and MySQL will insert current date and time. This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

set the 'type' of column named 'date_time' as 'DATETIME' and run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (`date_time`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the date in PHP as a timestamp, you can use the FROM_UNIXTIME function [1]

```
mysql> insert into table_name values (FROM_UNIXTIME(your_timestamp_here));
```

Hope it helped

[1]. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 1):

Remove the strtotime()

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
INSERT INTO my_table (date_time) VALUES ('$current_date')
```

If you want to include the hour, minutes and seconds,
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Answer (score 0):

You need to be mindful about single vs double quotes in PHP.
Single quote enclosed strings do not get parsed, while double-quote enclosed strings get parsed, so ('$current_date') will result in $current_date, but not the actual php set value.

See the example below:

```
$s = "dollars";
echo 'This costs a lot of $s.'; // This costs a lot of $s.
echo "This costs a lot of $s."; // This costs a lot of dollars.
```