# storing Time and Dates into an SQL database using php

Tags: php

How do I store dates and time from an online form I have into an SQL database using PHP? The date/time function is working quite ok.

Comment: Question is `too broad` . Have you googled before coming here ?

Comment: Ansers to this question to stackoverflow will be helpfull.[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671185/store-php-datetime-in-mysql-database

Comment: take value and put to database

Comment: Yeah. I"ve googled, just not giving me answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `datetime datatype` for your requirement. It will store both the date and time from your input field based on your query.

For retrieving the datetime you can use the mysql's `date_format()` function or PHP's `date()` function. The datetime will always be stored according to the server's time and not on the clients time.

Comment: normally we use the PHP date function and that way if you ever want to store the time relative to the user's timezone you can simply change the timezone based off the user's settings.

When you pull it out of the database, use strtotime() to convert it, then you can use all the date() features to display it however you want. Example:

echo date('F j, Y',strtotime($db_datetime));