# PHP,Mysql: Get hour,minutes and Store in Variable

Tags: php, mysql, time, hour

How can I store the actual hour and minute,from a mysql table, in variables?I want to store hour and minute like this:

```
//Connect database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","ufmg3duc");
  if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  //Select database
  mysql_select_db("stream_net", $con);

  //Read data
  $query_month = $_GET['form_month_tend'];
  $query_day = $_GET['form_day_tend'];
  $query_year = $_GET['form_year_tend'];
  if ($query_mes == NULL)
    $query_mes = date("m");
  if ($query_dia == NULL)
    $query_dia = date("d");
  if ($query_ano == NULL)
    $query_ano = date("Y");
```

How can i do like i did before but with Hour and MInutes?

Comment: Please, stop using `mysql_*` functions already. The entire extension is deprecated (and not a moment too soon). It's alternatives are far more powerful, reliable and up-to-date. These new extensions are `PDO` and `mysqli_*` (the `i` in `mysqli_*` stands for _improved_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[storing Time and Dates into an SQL database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115590/storing-time-and-dates-into-an-sql-database-using-php/20115658#20115658)

You should use the `datetime datatype` for your requirement. It will store both the date and time from your input field based on your query.

For retrieving the datetime you can use the mysql's `date_format()` function or PHP's `date()` function. The datetime will always be stored according to the server's time and not on the clients time.

**For Hour & Minute**

print date('H:i');

$hour = date('H');

$min = date('i');

Comment: +1 for the important hint: "The datetime will always be stored according to the server's time and not on the clients time."